# How to avoid fraud when purchasing a domain

Tags: domains, domain-registration, purchase

I have approached a domain owner about purchasing their domain. We have agreed on a price, what is the safest/best way to send them payment and ensure I receive the domain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some website that offer "escrow" services:

- https://www.escrow.com/
- http://www.sedo.com/us/services/domain-escrow/

Selling/buying a domain is safe that way.

You can also do a down-payment (lets say 50%), the owner transfers the domain, and you pay the other 50%. The latter is more about trust.

Comment: Escrow.com is the only online escrow service to trust. I've used them a few times more than 5 years ago and had no problems with getting paid from them. Sedo.com or GoDaddy are also good for domain transfers.